# Proof followed by additive functions

Tags: real-analysis, functions

it is asked to prove that for an additive function $f$,  $f(mx) = mf(x)$, for all integer values of m. I have proved for m = 0 and for the positive values of m using mathematical induction. but I can't prove that for the negative integer values of m. some one help me with this

Comment: Hint : use the fact that $f(0)=f(x-x)$

Comment: More information about the function $f(x)$ is needed. For instance, the function $f(x)=\begin{cases}x &\text{if $x\geq 0$}\\ 0 &\text{if $x<0$}\end{cases}$ satisfies that $f(mx)=m\cdot f(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and $m\in\mathbb{Z}^{\geq 0}$, but it does not satisfy that $f(-1)=-f(1)$.

Comment: His function is meant to be additive.